# Assign values to an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

The data structure for my project is supposed to look like:

```
{
"result":"ok",
"content":[
    {
        "type":"1d",
        "lower":1359129600,
        "upper":1359133200,
        "mean":29.071428571428573

    },{
        "type":"1d",
        "lower":1359133200,
        "upper":1359136800,
        "mean":27.232142857142858
    }]
}
```

I am trying to assign values for lower, upper, mean.

```
var dataResult = {result:"ok", content:[{type:"1d", lower:"", upper:"", mean:""}]};
var scope = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: scope.fetchUrl,
    data: { query: dataQuery }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      for(var i = 0; i < data["reading_list"].length; i++){
        dataResult.content[i].lower = convertToUnix(data["reading_list"][i]["ts"]);
      }
```

I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lower' of undefined" and I'm don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error means that `dataResult.content[i]` returns `undefined`. You cannot set a property on `undefined`. Simple test: `var foo; foo.bar = 42;`. Why is it `undefined`? Because the value of `i` is not a property of `dataResult.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "content" array starts off with just one object in it. If your ajax result has more than that, then those array entries will be `undefined`.

Before trying to do the assignment, just make sure the array element has an object in it:

```
    if (!dataResult.content[i])
      dataResult.content[i] = {};
    dataResult.content[i].lower = convertToUnix(data["reading_list"][i]["ts"]);
```

Comment: The error is no longer there but when I console.log `dataResult.content.lower` to see the output, it shows undefined.

Comment: @user2100620 well `dataResult.content` is the whole array itself; you need to log the whole array or else individual elements of the array. The array doesn't have a "lower" property, but the individual elements do.

Comment: Thank you! This all makes a lot more sense now